# How to update a field inside an array object in Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-1.7.5

Below is a snippet from ES response body. What I want is to update the field inside labels array like for ex "Y" to "Y". I tried `"labels.Y":"Y"` but it created a field with key `"labels.Y"` and value `"Y"`. But not traversed to the field inside the `labels[0]`.

```
---> "labels": [
                {
                    "X": "x",
                    "Y": "y",
                    "Z": "z",
                    "W": "w",
                    "V": "v",
                    "A": "a"
                }
            ],
```

Comment: did you try labels[0].Y ?

Comment: Thanks Martin, but I have tried that as well. It is adding that as well as key.